# inheritance related problem in c#

Tags: c#

i learnt that private members are available in sub class in c# but we cant use these then what is the use of those private members n sub class and how can i access those private member in sub class please let me now i am not getting this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i learnt that private members are available in sub class in c#

You learned wrong. Private members are not accessible to subclasses. They are visible only inside the current class (ignoring reflection of course). Only public and protected members are accessible in subclasses. Here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) which covers the different access modifiers.

Comment: what is this then......................................................"A derived class has access to the public, protected, internal, and protected internal members of a base class. Even though a derived class inherits the private members of a base class, it cannot access those members.

Comment: However, all those private members are still present in the derived class and can do the same work they would do in the base class itself. For example, suppose that a protected base class method accesses a private field. That field has to be present in the derived class in order for the inherited base class method to work properly."

Comment: That means that the private stuff is there, because it's been declared in a superclass (base class), but your subclass's code can't touch it or even see it (short of using reflection).  Only code declared in the base class can touch the stuff that the base class has declared "private".

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Private members cannot be accessed in derived classes and that's how mother nature created the .NET framework. I don't see what's the problem here.

Comment: i mean i am confuse with this..."However, all those private members are still present in the derived class and can do the same work they would do in the base class itself"

Comment: The data's there, but you can't directly mess with it.  The functions are there, but you can't call them.  If you're meant to use the stuff, the base class will define a public or protected API that will get or set the data or call the function for you.  But you should never have to care about anything that's private, and you should never try to get around the restrictions that `private` creates.  (There are exceptions, but if you have to ask, they don't apply to you and won't for a LONG time.)